# Referenced variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function within a module (setup.js) where I want to use it but also reference the exact same variable in another module (config.js).

Unfortunately at the moment I get 'undefined' when trying to reference the required exported variable from another module.

```
setup.js

    let randomString = function() {
        return Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);;
    };
    
    console.log(randomString());
    //SxIARFSSvw

    module.exports = randomString;
```

Imported in another file

```
config.js

    const setup = require('./setup');
    console.log(setup.randomString);
    //undefined, looking for SxIARFSSvw
```

Apologies this is likely something simple I am missing but can't see it.

Comment: Try `console.log(setup());`  — the value of `setup` will be the function itself.

Comment: `setup` *is* `randomString`. Not an object containing a property `randomString`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `module.exports = randomString;` to `module.exports = {randomString: randomString};`

Comment: or use auto-value syntax: `module.exports = { randomString }`